# Why can't I pass the code test in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what 
I 
met 
is 
a code question below:
https://www.patest.cn/contests/pat-a-practise/1001

> Calculate a + b and output the sum in standard format -- that is, the digits must be separated into groups of three by commas (unless there are less than four digits).
>
> Input
>
> Each input file contains one test case. Each case contains a pair of integers a and b where -1000000 <= a, b <= 1000000. The numbers are separated by a space.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, you should output the sum of a and b in one line. The sum must be written in the standard format.
>
> Sample Input
>
> -1000000 9
>
> Sample Output
>
> -999,991

This is my code below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    aline = input()
    astr,bstr = aline.strip().split()
    a,b = int(astr),int(bstr)
    sum = a + b
    sumstr= str(sum)
    result = ''
    while sumstr:
        sumstr, aslice = sumstr[:-3], sumstr[-3:]
        if sumstr:
            result = ',' + aslice + result
        else:
            result = aslice + result

    print(result)
```

And the test result turn out to be :

> 时间(Time)       结果(test result)  得分(score)  题目(question number)
>
> 语言(programe language)  用时(ms)[time consume]    内存(kB)[memory]  用户[user]
>
> 8月22日 15:46    **部分正确[Partial Correct]**(Why?!!!)  11  1001
>
> Python (python3 3.4.2) 25  3184    polar9527
>
> 测试点[test point]    结果[result]   用时(ms)[time consume]   内存(kB)[memory]  得分[score]/满分[full credit]
>
> 0  答案错误[wrong]     25  3056    0/9
>
> 1  答案正确[correct]   19  3056    1/1
>
> 10 答案正确[correct]   18  3184    1/1
>
> 11 答案正确[correct]   19  3176    1/1
>
> 2  答案正确[correct]   17  3180    1/1
>
> 3  答案正确[correct]   16  3056    1/1
>
> 4  答案正确[correct]   14  3184    1/1
>
> 5  答案正确[correct]   17  3056    1/1
>
> 6  答案正确[correct]   19  3168    1/1
>
> 7  答案正确[correct]   22  3184    1/1
>
> 8  答案正确[correct]   21  3164    1/1
>
> 9  答案正确[correct]   15  3184    1/1

Comment: Is this the result of the code you posted?

Comment: The first line (`if __name__` etc.) is superfluous, but I wouldn't go so far as saying it is actually *wrong*.  After that those next three lines could be written several ways, including in just one line (which personally I hate).

Comment: this is  the result of the code I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you a simple that doesn't match answer, when you enter -1000000, 9 as a, b in your input, you'll get -,999,991.which is wrong.

To get the right answer, you really should get to know format in python.

To solve this question, you can just write your code like this.

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    aline = input()
    astr,bstr = aline.strip().split()
    a,b = int(astr),int(bstr)
    sum = a + b
    print('{:,}'.format(sum))`

Comment: you are so impish for the author of this code question in some sense.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the behavior of your code when you input -1000 and 1. You need to handle the minus sign, because it is not a digit.